# How make my menu active class

Tags: php, menu

I looking for 2h over the net and I can't find nothing to work for my menu, to make the active page to look another way.
Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Whats New!</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
<div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
</div>
```

if one of the li line is like that:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

the button look different, i try with php, jquery, but nothing work, so i need something to put 'class=active' to my li from the current page.

Comment: Can you put the the href values?  Is this a single page app a page for each link? In this case it will make a difference.

Comment: I found a simple solution in php " <li <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="active"';?>><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li> " put this line on every li

Answer (score 1):

Try this full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

 <!-- javascript -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {


  $('.menu ul li').click(function(){
        $('.menu ul li').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
     });

  });
 </script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Whats New!</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
<div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
```

click here to live demo http://jsfiddle.net/Yn2RY/2/

Comment: it works but only for example I click on Home button it works, if i close the browser and open my index.php donsen't work :| it must to click once time on button you to work...

Answer (score 1):

So you can put your current page name to your php script and then loop the menu.

```
$curr_page = 'Here is your current page name(one of the $pages)';

$pages = array('Home', 'About', 'Whats New!', 'Products', 'FAQ', 'Support');

echo '<div class="menu"><ul>';

foreach($pages as $page) {
    if($page == $curr_page) {
        echo "<li class="active"><a href="#">$page</a></li>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<li><a href="#">$page</a></li>";
    }
}

echo '<div class="clear"></div></div></ul>';
```

Another example in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var curr_page = "Here is your current page name";

    $('.menu > ul > li').each(function() {
        if($(this).text() == curr_page) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return false;
        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

In foreach statement you can see shorthand construction that decides, if that li is active or not. Variable currentPage holds name of page, that is same as one of the values in array. You can get currentPage for example from $_GET.

Code:

```
<?php $menu = array("Home",
                    "About",
                    "Whats New!",
                    "Products",
                    "FAQ",
                    "Support",) ?>

<div class="menu">
<ul>
<?php 

foreach($menu as $item)
{
  $active = ($item==$currentPage) ? " class='active'" : '';
  echo "<li><a href="$item"$active>$item</a></li>";
}
?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article that describes how to get the current page url:
[Get current page url](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/get-current-page-url/)

Then you can have logic like this,

```
<?php 
  if ($currenturl == $Thisurl)
  echo "class=""active"";
?>
```